# Accessing website content in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm looking for how to access information on a website from a Windows Phone 7 device, without opening a brower window.  For example, if I had a website that provided a daily dictionary word and definition, how could I navigate to that word in my wp7 app without opening the whole page for display?

In a sense the app would be a page scraper, just looking for some of the data on a page.

I know how to open a web browser programmatically, but haven't been able to find out how to get a page's content without a browser window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull http data down using WebClient (if trivial volume) or HttpWebRequest (better for UI thread responsiveness).

API's here for your reference.

[HttpWebRequest Class (System.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

[WebClient Class (System.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

A demo project showing both in use here.

[WebClient, HttpWebRequest and the UI Thread on Windows Phone 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8)

You'll then need to parse the html you pull down to get out of it what you want.

Comment: I beat you to it, Mick!  I found your demo project in a search of the Windows Phone 7 forums, possibly before you posted it here -- but in any case it worked swimmingly!  Thanks!